# How to validate a string of numbers and commas, but not alpha chars

Tags: php, regex

How can I write a regex to be used in PHP (preg_match) to only validate numbers and commas (optionally)? I come up with this:

```
[,0-9]+
```

but it doesn't seem to work. this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
1 -> OK
1,2 -> OK
1,2,3 -> OK
abc -> NO
1,a -> NO
1,2,a -> NO
1, a, 2 -> NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: `^[,0-9]+$`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/autbaM/1)

Code:

```
$re = '/^[,0-9]+$/m';
$str = '1
1,2
1,2,3
abc
1,a
1,2,a
1, a, 2
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```